# How to add app icon properly in android react-native

Tags: android, react-native, appicon

Hi I added icons to android/app/src/main/res/..., the app icon showing perfectly in home screen like first image, but when minimize the app it showing default app icon like second image. how can change that icon also.
I cleaned build folder, gradlew and reinstalled the app but no changes.
Please help me on this

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: did you check my answer?

Comment: After clear cache in mobile device the app icon appears properly

Answer (score 0):

put this on AndroidManifest.xml and try

```
<application
      ...
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
      ...
</application>
```

also hope you update the icons properly. please refer this
https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-update-the-launcher-icon-for-your-android-app--cms-30624

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this comes after you setup androidManifest.xml but you will need icons in these two folders:

- android/app/src/main/res/mipmap.
- ios//Images.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset

I've used the [resize-reactnative-launcher-icon](https://github.com/lszyba1/resize-reactnative-launcher-icon?utm_source=stackoverflow.com) shell scrip to generate my icons. It takes a png image and creates the 25 variations you need by size and resolution.

[bash resize.sh my-cool-new-app-logo.png](http://wwwhww.news/u/cwSNkeLNXf#How%20to%20modify%20or%20replace%20icon%20for%20reactnative%20app)